# Under Chrome error message that SO JS blocked

Tags: bug

SO is working with Brave. I've made no changes to plugins and this started within the last 6 hours.

[image: This shows the error message]

Comment: No issues here.  Must be local to you.

Comment: the js files from somewhere aren't loading. could be that they are blocked by your firewall or your browser just likes to kill random stuff for the hell of it (cheeky bugger) or something else. if you open up the developer tool (F12), go to network and reload the page you should see what libraries fail. run the addresses they list (right click on filename -> open in new tab) you should see more info on why your not getting the file (if the status wasn't enough)

Comment: Okay, somehow this has been cleared by rebooting.